# regex - exclude

Tags: regex, words

I have this regex

```
(?!L[aAOo]s\b|Se\b|El\b|La\b|Lo\b|Los\b|Las\b|Este\b|ese\b|Aquel\b|Esta\b|Esa\b|Aquella\b|Estos\b|Esos\b|Aquellos\b|Estas\b|Esas\b|Aquellas\b|Mi\b|Tu\b|Su\b|Mis\b|Tus\b|sus\b|Mio\b|Mia\b|Tuyo\b|Tuya\b|Suyo\b|Suya\b|algún\b|alguna\b|algunos\b|algunas\b|ningún\b|ninguna\b|ningunos\b|ningunas\b|bastante\b|bastantes\b|otro\b|otra\b|otros\b|otras\b|cierto\b|cierta\b|ciertos\b|ciertas\b|poco\b|poca\b|pocos\b|pocas\b|cualquier\b|cualquiera\b|cualesquiera\b|demasiado\b|demasiada\b|demasiados\b|demasiadas\b|tal\b|tales\b|escasos\b|escasas\b|tanto\b|tanta\b|tantos\b|tantas\b|cada\b|todo\b|toda\b|todos\b|todas\b|más\b|menos\b|unos\b|unas\b|mucho\b|muchas\b|muchos\b|muchas\b|Un\b|De\b|En\b|Si\b|SALUD\b)[A-Z][a-zA-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúñ]+
```

that exclude all that words and accept capital words and and words starting with a capital word. 
I cant add the word SALUD to be excluded, why?

I am trying here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Please list examples of what you want to match and what you want to not match. Also you tegex has some basic errors regarding use of logical OR: you need to use brackets. Further, your regex is ridiculously long - only show as few terms as possible to demonstrate the problem. See [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: What you have does indeed exclude "SALUD" as a match.  I will match the "ALUD" from "SALUD", and won't exclude "Salud".  Also, worth noting that there is a large portion of your regex excluding words which are all lowercase, none of whichwill be matched by the regex anyway.

Comment: First of all thanks and sorry about my english and short mesagge.

What I am needing is this:
1- Match all capital WORDS
2- Match all word with the first letter Capital
3- Match all words with capital WORDS and dots between letters, like F.M.I
4- Include this letters áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ

5- Exlude a list of words with first letter Capital, like this: En La El Los Ese 
6- Exlude a list of words with all letters capital, like SALUD

Comment: when I put include this letters áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ I wanted to say that words that are matched can have those letters, like Súarez

Answer (score 0):

apply `\b[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ](([.]?[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ])*|[a-záéíóúñ]*)\b` to match words according to your requirements 1-4. there is no reasonable way of excluding matches from the lists 5, 6 by enhancing this regex. you rather test the matches against a dictionary or a second regex containing all 'forbidden' terms as alternatives. remember to add start/end markers to avoid unwanted partial matches.

i.e. `^(El|La|...|SALUD)$` (replace the ellipsis by the alternation of all other blacklisted words)

Comment: the way the code points are specified, in nfc; as far as i understand there is ana equivalent nfd representation for each of the diacrtical characters. whatever the actual representation of the string the regex  matches against, it is the responsibility of the regex engine to assure the match of code points equivalent under different normalization strategies; in case there are non-matches due to nfc/nfd differences they can always be remedied by specifying the equivalent code point sequences as macthing alternatives; admittedly this will turn out ugly.

Comment: You will have to convert the string to NFC then for this to work.  It will not work to convert the pattern to NFD or else your character classes will get screwy. The regex engine cannot do this for you, either.   Also, since this is Spanish, it looks like the OP forgot that `ü` and `Ü` can happen, too.  This sort of thing is usually better approached using Unicode regex properties like `\pL` or even `\X` if you have it.